# How to zoom in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider we have a `div` with an image in it. So when we hover over it it zooms. The div doesn't changes it's position or size instead it's children looks zoomed.
How can we do it in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hover event to the div and change the css zoom attribute of the image.

jQuery (assuming the div has the class name of **box**)

```
var div = $('.box');

div.hover(function(){
    div.children('img').css({'zoom':'1.5'}); 
}, function(){
    div.children('img').css({'zoom': '1'});
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pMP38/)

Comment: Instead of zoom, which is non-standard, you should recommend transforms (for modern browsers) and fallback to filters (for old-IE). A link for documentation: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/